# Mysql from_unixtime same date time from two different timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, mariadb

I am having a weird problem with mysql. 
I am using FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP to convert timestamp to datetime.
The problem is two different timestamp is resulting into same datetime. How can it be possible?

Here what I got from mysql-

```
SELECT from_unixtime( '1456017720' ) , from_unixtime( '1456021320' )
```

Output-

> 2016-02-20 23:22:00   2016-02-20 23:22:00

[image]

This is the result of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

```
innodb_version 5.6.26-76.0 
protocol_version 10 
slave_type_conversions version 10.0.23-MariaDB 
version_comment MariaDB Server 
version_compile_machine x86_64 
version_compile_os Linux 
version_malloc_library bundled jemalloc
```

Comment: What's the server's time zone?

Comment: Try giving it int (without quotes) instead of string?

Comment: Different result here: `2016-02-21 02:22:00 | 2016-02-21 03:22:00`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález its UTC -2

Comment: @Flyer same result :(

Comment: Strange I get `2016-02-21 01:22:00.000000` and `2016-02-21 02:22:00.000000` using a string or a number

Comment: @EugenRieck yeah, it should be different. even my localhost is giving correct result. but production server is giving this incorrect result :(

Comment: What happens if you give a format in parameter 2. `SELECT from_unixtime(1456017720, GET_FORMAT(DATETIME,'EUR')) , from_unixtime(1456021320, GET_FORMAT(DATETIME,'EUR'))`

Comment: Do you know the exact time zone name (rather than the UTC offset)? What country is the data center at?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Surely as this is being run in the same select statement on the same server at the same time, timezones are irrellevent

Comment: @RiggsFolly The unix timestamps differ exactly in 3600 seconds (1 hour). So you can get the same local time if the server is configured in a time zone that swaps regular time to daylight saving time right then.

Comment: @RiggsFolly same output :( nothing changed http://prntscr.com/a5rkhm

Comment: ... though it doesn't make sense that it happens exactly at 2:22 ...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález But I have to assume he ran this more than once when he noticed the problem to check, so a daylight saving switch over is not going to explain this happening more that once. I would humbly suggest

Comment: Is it only these 2 numbers that this happens to, or can you make it happen with other numbers

Comment: @RiggsFolly it happens with many other numbers too. I was debugging an application for bugs. Later I found this problem with mysql server.

Comment: What version of MYSQL are you running on the server giving these problems. `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

Comment: @RiggsFolly
It shows the following-

`Variable_name  Value  
innodb_version  5.6.26-76.0
protocol_version  10
slave_type_conversions  
version  10.0.23-MariaDB
version_comment  MariaDB Server
version_compile_machine  x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
version_malloc_library  bundled jemalloc`

Comment: You do know that `mariadb` is not `mysql` dont you? Similiar but NOT THE SAME

Comment: File a bug with maridb.com .

Comment: Not so fast @RickJames.  There are transitions in several time zones into "AMT" ("Amazonas?") and "BRT" ("Brasilia?") between these two unixtimes in the MySQL time zone tables.  These two time zones appear to have left daylight time on Feb. 22.  Not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone after all these years, I had a similar issue.

```
SELECT from_unixtime( timestamp,  '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%m:%s') , from_unixtime( differenttimestamp, '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%m:%s' )
```

...returning the same values. What I figured out is that %m stands for month, not minutes. Changed it to %i and the problem disappears. So, definitely my mistake in formatting. This could be related to your problem as well, a bug in default formatting. The workaround would be using a format string, but not an incorrect one as I did in my example above.